# Running Ptr-Net on MXNet

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, mxnet

We have a Ptr-Net model that we want to run. Can the MXNet be useful for this scenario. If not, what are the other libraries that we can use to run Ptr-Net models?

We are building a Ptr-Net model using TensorFlow as of now.

Answer (score 1):

Currently we don't have a complete model for Ptr-Net, but you can define symbolic model for Ptr-Net. Here is a complete example for creating char-level lstm model: http://mxnet.io/tutorials/python/char_lstm.html